# Need help on java2wsdl using gradle

Tags: gradle, java2wsdl

I have a java project to which I build it using gradle build and generate a war file.

Currently my requirement is to generate WSDL file at the time of build from java classes. I came to know about **axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin** and found the syntax of applying it in gradle. But I am not able to get the tasks list or the example of using this plugin in gradle to generate the WSDL file using this plugin.

Can anybody let me know of how to use this plugin or any other help so that I can generate WSDL file form my java classes.

---

Dependency section which I included in build.gradle:

```
repositories    {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    'org.apache.axis2:axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin:1.6.2'
}
```

Comment: What did you do so far ?

Comment: I added the plugin details in dependencies section and searched for task name to execute, but I couldnt find any using gradle tasks command.

Comment: Could you share this in your question ?

Comment: I dont have any background of it and simply mentioned the dependency in code like in updated question. Then I ran gradle tasks to get task list which I can run but didnt find any answer

Answer (score 1):

`axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin` is a `maven` plugin not a `gradle` one.

Moreoever, gradle plugins must be defined in [a `buildscript` closure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript) or a [`plugins` one](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) if you want to use the new plugins DSL.

Here, you are just using the maven plugin as a regular dependency for your project.

As far as i know, there is not "java2wsdl" gradle plugin.